# Mouse remote control

Tags: python, sockets, udp, mouse, pyautogui

Trying to implement some kind of [synergy](https://symless.com/synergy) on python using PyAutoGui and socket communication.
The idea is to control mouse and keyboard of another computer on LAN by using mouse/keyboard of a server computer.
By now it's only mouse movement implementaion.
Here are some classes:

Server part:

```
class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.ip = get_ip()
        self.port = 3000
        self.transfer_mod = False
        self.client_address = ""

    def start(self):
        print("Started server with ip: {}".format(self.ip))
        self.s.bind((self.ip, self.port))
        self.get_connection()

    def get_connection(self):
        print("Waiting for connection...")
        while True:
            request, self.client_address = self.s.recvfrom(4096)
            if request:
                self.s.sendto(request, self.client_address)
                print("{} connected!".format(self.client_address))
                break

    def enable_transfer(self):
        print("Transfer to {} enabled".format(self.client_address))
        self.transfer_mod = True
        transfer_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.transfer_mouse)
        transfer_thread.start()

    def disable_transfer(self):
        print("Transfer to {} disabled".format(self.client_address))
        self.transfer_mod = False

    def transfer_mouse(self):
        previous_pos = (-1, -1)
        while self.transfer_mod:
            pos = pyautogui.position()

            if pos != previous_pos:
                data = pickle.dumps(pos)
                self.s.sendto(data, self.client_address)
                sleep(0.1)

            previous_pos = pos

    def close(self):
        self.disable_transfer()
        self.s.close()
```

Client part:

```
class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.port = 3000
        self.connection = False

    def connect(self, server_ip):
        request = bytes("Request","utf-8")
        self.s.sendto(request, (server_ip, self.port))
        received, address = self.s.recvfrom(4096)
        if received == request:
            print("Connected to {}".format(server_ip))
            self.connection = True
            threading.Thread(target=self.receive_data).start()

    def receive_data(self):
        while self.connection:
            data, server = self.s.recvfrom(4096)
            pos = pickle.loads(data)
            self.control_mouse(pos)

    def disconnect(self):
        print("Disconnected from the server")
        self.connection = False

    def control_mouse(self, position):
        pyautogui.moveTo(position[0], position[1])

    def close(self):
        self.disconnect()
        self.s.close()
```

So, the problem of that is the speed of mouse movement on client computer is so low. It seems there are too many exceed packets or something like that. So, the question itself: Is it a good way of implementing this idea, if yes, what's the problem of that script, if no, any advises on how to do it more properly?

Comment: Is there a reason you are attempting to do this? There's plenty of ways to accomplish this without writing your own code.

Comment: @asdf i just like writing my own code

Comment: @IlyaLasy did you find any solution?